# Neither :contains or .contains working

Tags: jquery, contains

I'm trying to get the value of a select.

The select has a long, computed ID generated by the CMS, so I need to use *= to get the select which has an ID which contains 'mySelect'.

If the value of this select is the word 'Select' (which means you haven't chosen an option), then do something. I also need to repeat this elsewhere for if other options are chosen on other selects, this is just one example.
This is my code...

```
var selectValue = $('select[id*="mySelect"]').val();  
console.log(selectValue)  
if ((selectValue + ':contains("Select")')) 
    {
    $alert('select chosen');
}
else {
    $alert('other chosen');
}
```

This is all wrapped in a function called on document ready and also when changing the select.

When I choose an option in the select, the console log shows selectValue as being '1' for example, but the select chosen alert ONLY shows.

I also tried it this way, which does work but only in Firefox. In all other browsers I get a console error 'Object doesn't support property or method 'contains'.

```
var selectValue = $('select[id*="mySelect"]').val();  
if (selectValue.contains('Select')) 
    {
    $alert('select chosen');
}
else {
    $alert('other chosen');
}
```

Any suggestions please? I need to use some method of contains for quite a few things, this is just one example.

Comment: `$alert`? What is that? `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to check if a string contains another string is `indexOf`:

```
if ( selectValue.indexOf( 'Search' ) > !== -1 ) {
```

The ECMAScript 6 `.contains()` method makes this check simpler (and more readable), but so far it's only implemented in Firefox: